# I can't receive POST requisitions in my NodeJs server

Tags: node.js

I'm really really new with NodeJs (I have some knowledge of C# Asp.Net MVC and Rails, so I already got the MVC concepts).
I'm following the book The Node Beginner (by Manuel Kiessling). I just stucked at point where I created a simple form with submit button.
The point is that I'm not catching the post in my server side.

This is my server code:

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");

function start(route, handle) {
    function onRequest(request, response) {
        var postData = "";

        var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
        console.log("Requisition received for " + pathname + ".");

        request.setEncoding("utf8");

        request.on("data", function(postDataChunk) {
            postData += postDataChunk;
            console.log("Receiving part of data from POST '" + postDataChunk + "'.");
        });

        request.addListener("end", function() {
            route(handle, pathname, response, postData);
        });
    }

    http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
    console.log("Server started");
}

exports.start = start;
```

When I start my application and go to localhost:8888/start I get in console all the log output. But when I fill the form and try submit, nothing happens.
[image: Console Output]

What am I doing wrong? Post is also a request, right? Why the line console.log("Requisition received for " + pathname + "."); is not being executed when I clik on submit?

PS: All code and other modules can be found on my github https://github.com/ricardovsilva/nodeJs-beginnerBook

Comment: Strongly recommend using a Framework like Hapi or Express with APIs for all of this rather than trying to reinvent the wheel, even as a learning exercise. You mentioned ASP.net, would you code your own framework in C# instead of using it? Or a rails alternative in Ruby?

Comment: I know that, for any enterprise application I will search and use an already build framework. But the point that I most liked in this book is explain how the "wheel" works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cloned your repo and took a look at it. It looks like you're missing a closing quotation mark on the `content` attribute of your meta tag :)

I really hate putting markup in magic strings like that (for this very reason), but if it's something you must do then I recommend this little trick to make it easier to read:

```
var body = [
  '<html>',
  '  <head>',
  '    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />',
  '  </head>',
  '  <body>',
  '    <form action="/upload" method="POST">',
  '      <textarea name="text" rows="20" cols="60"></textarea>',
  '      <input type="submit" value="Send text" />',
  '    </form>',
  '  </body>',
  '</html>'
].join('');
```

That way all your tag indentation is part of the string and won't get mangle by your code formatter if you have one.

With all that said, after you've done your basic learning with your book I highly recommend digging into a framework such as [Express](http://expressjs.com/).

PS - The "Network" tab in Chrome's developer tools is your friend :D

[image]

You can see from there that your form isn't making a request to the server at all :)

Comment: Express is on the list! :), thanks for all the help.

Comment: No problem. Oh! And don't forget that the network tab in Chrome's dev tools is your friend :D. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
When I look to html generated by inspector, I saw that form was not being created.
Looking more deep into html in that I was generating, I saw that was faulting one ", and this was breaking the html.
In real, POST was never happening.
Solved this, everything is working now.
I also updated the code on github.

Comment: Hahaha, no problem. But you exemplified better the problem. Others may pass for the same problem than me, and your explanation was really better than mine! Thanks for help!